# Why my rcpp code is not much too fast using openmp parallelization

Tags: openmp, rcpp

I try to use openmp to parallelise my loop to be faster. The problem is that the parallelised version is not faster than the sequential version

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
#include <iostream>
// [[Rcpp::plugins(openmp)]]
#include <omp.h>
#include "test.h"

using namespace std;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
std::vector<double> parallel_random_sum(int n, int ncores) {

  std::vector<double> res(n);

#pragma omp parallel num_threads(ncores)
{
#pragma omp for
  for (int j = 0; j < n; ++j) {
    double lres(0);
   // cout << "j = "<<j <<" test = " << lres<<endl;
    lres += j;
    res[j] = lres / n;
  } 
}

return res;
}

// [[Rcpp::export]]
std::vector<double> not_parallel_random_sum(int n) {

  std::vector<double> res(n);

  for (int j = 0; j < n; ++j) {
    double lres(0);
  //  cout << "j = "<<j <<" test = " << lres<<endl;
    lres += j;
    res[j] = lres / n;
  }

return res;
}

/*** R
microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
  parallel_random_sum(1e7, 8),
  not_parallel_random_sum(1e7),
  times = 20
) 
  */
```

result ==>

1. parallel_random_sum(1e+07,8)  62.02360 milliseconds
2. not_parallel_random_sum(1e+07)  65.56082 milliseconds

Comment: That code looks a lot like http://www.daqana.org/dqrng/articles/parallel.html#xoroshiro-jump-ahead-with-openmp ;-) Note that there a small number of long vectors is used, each is summed in parallel. If you want to sum a single vector, you should split it into a few parts (serial), sum each individually (in parallel), and combine the results (serial).

Comment: No, but if I want to perform a different treatment on each element of the for loop. Ex : for i=1 compute the sum of 1 elements, for i =2 compute the sum of 2  éléments .. and for i = n compute the sum of n elements ..

Comment: Wouldn't that be `cumsum`?

Comment: Couple of notes, you can't really using any _Rcpp_ / _R_ objects due to multithreading issues that parallelization brings in. So, when you are using the parallelization safe `std::vector<T>`, there is a deep copy required when importing the object back into _R_. This is largely being picked up on the benchmark with a high amount of observations.

Comment: how can i test if openmp rcpp work ?

Comment: How can i configure openmp on R ??

Answer (score 0):

The code you are trying to parallelize is just not expensive enough, making the overhead of the parallelization comparable to the gain. If you add some artificial workload in the loop by sleeping for a short amount of time, you can see the performance gain:

```cpp
#include <chrono>
#include <thread>
#include <Rcpp.h>
// [[Rcpp::plugins(openmp)]]
#include <omp.h>
// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppParallel)]]
#include <RcppParallel.h>

// [[Rcpp::export]]
Rcpp::NumericVector parallel_sleep(int n, int ncores) {

  Rcpp::NumericVector res_(n);
  RcppParallel::RVector<double> res(res_);

#pragma omp parallel num_threads(ncores)
{
#pragma omp for
  for (int j = 0; j < n; ++j) {
    double lres(0);
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::microseconds(10));
    lres += j;
    res[j] = lres / n;
  }
}

return res_;
}

// [[Rcpp::export]]
Rcpp::NumericVector not_parallel_sleep(int n) {

  Rcpp::NumericVector res(n);

  for (int j = 0; j < n; ++j) {
    double lres(0);
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::microseconds(10));
    lres += j;
    res[j] = lres / n;
  }

  return res;
}

/*** R
N <- 1e4
bench::mark(
  parallel_sleep(N, 8),
  not_parallel_sleep(N)
) 
*/
```

Result:

```
# A tibble: 2 x 14
  expression         min     mean   median   max `itr/sec` mem_alloc  n_gc n_itr total_time result   memory    time  gc     
  <chr>         <bch:tm> <bch:tm> <bch:tm> <bch>     <dbl> <bch:byt> <dbl> <int>   <bch:tm> <list>   <list>    <lis> <list> 
1 parallel_sle…   73.2ms   81.3ms   82.3ms  87ms     12.3     80.7KB     0     7      569ms <dbl [1… <Rprofme… <bch… <tibbl…
2 not_parallel…  667.8ms  667.8ms  667.8ms 668ms      1.50    80.7KB     0     1      668ms <dbl [1… <Rprofme… <bch… <tibbl…
```

Note that I am also using data structures from RcppParallel to avoid the need of a deep copy when returning the data (c.f. comment by @coatless).